# Define a function to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, function

Consider this code in Python

```
filter_2020 = hdb_million[hdb_million["year"]==2020]
town_2020 = filter_2020["town"].unique()
results_2020 = len(town_2020)
print(town_2020)
print("in 2020 the number of towns are:", results_2020)
print("\n")

filter_2021 = hdb_million[hdb_million["year"]==2021]
town_2021 = filter_2021["town"].unique()
results_2021 = len(town_2021)
print(town_2021)
print("in 2021 the number of towns are:", results_2021)
print("\n")

filter_2022 = hdb_million[hdb_million["year"]==2022]
town_2022 = filter_2022["town"].unique()
results_2022 = len(town_2022)
print(town_2022)
```

Output

```
['BUKIT MERAH' 'CLEMENTI' 'TOA PAYOH' 'KALLANG/WHAMPOA' 'QUEENSTOWN'
 'BISHAN' 'CENTRAL AREA' 'ANG MO KIO' 'GEYLANG']
in 2020 the number of towns are: 9

['BISHAN' 'BUKIT MERAH' 'CENTRAL AREA' 'CLEMENTI' 'QUEENSTOWN' 'SERANGOON'
 'TOA PAYOH' 'BUKIT TIMAH' 'KALLANG/WHAMPOA' 'ANG MO KIO']
in 2021 the number of towns are: 10

['ANG MO KIO' 'BISHAN' 'BUKIT TIMAH' 'CENTRAL AREA' 'CLEMENTI' 'GEYLANG'
 'KALLANG/WHAMPOA' 'QUEENSTOWN' 'SERANGOON' 'TOA PAYOH' 'BUKIT MERAH'
 'YISHUN' 'PASIR RIS' 'WOODLANDS' 'BUKIT BATOK' 'HOUGANG' 'MARINE PARADE'
 'PUNGGOL' 'TAMPINES' 'BEDOK']
in 2022 the number of towns are: 20
```

Instead of repeating the codes, can I define a function to arrive at the same output ? I tried several def functions but am not successful. Most grateful for any insights. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the print things to be repeated using a function.

```
def print_town_info(year, town_input):
    filter_year = town_input[town_input["year"] == year]
    town = filter_year["town"].unique()
    print(town)
    print("in " + str(year) + " the number of towns are:", len(town))
    print("\n")
```

Then if you want it in a loop:

```
for y in [2020, 2021, 2022]:
    print_town_info(y, hdb_million)
```

Comment: Many thanks AER. I struggled a bit to understand why do we need 2 arguments in       def print_town_info(year, town_input):  .. I tried the following and it seems to work              def print_town_info(year):                                                                                                         filter_year=hdb_million[hdb_million["year"] == year]  .. with the rest of your codes. Is my code technically correct

Comment: More if you want to use a different dataframe that's all. Sure, if it works that's also fine. I just don't like assuming variables inside functions. But yes, if it's already defined in that file it'll work. Remember to accept the answer as well (points for you) if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through a loop,

```
for year in [2020, 2021, 2022]:
    filter_year = hdb_million[hdb_million["year"]== year]
    town = filter_year["town"].unique()
    results = len(town)
    print(town)
    print(f"in {year} the number of towns are:", results)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: As much as it's an option. I think they were looking for a function with a `def`